# why PyQt5 QWindow.setScreen() not working?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to run a Qt QML application on secondary screen, but it is not working. I am using PyCharm as IDE and PyQt5.

I do have second screen connected physically. and app runs correctly on primary screen but even if I try to set Window screen to secondary it is not working.
Already have tried:

```py
self.app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
self.engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
# ...
self.engine.load(my_qml_name)
# ...
qW = QWindow(self.app.topLevelWindows()[0])
qW.setScreen(self.app.screens()[1])
```

I get the app running on my primary screen only.

P.S.: My topLevelWindow is a QQuickWindow and not QWindow.

Comment: does `qW.windowHandle().setScreen(self.app.screens()[1])` work?

Comment: No, it doesn't, it says qW don't have the windowHandle() attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not cast self.app.topLevelWindows()[0] to anything.

The code should look like this

```py
self.app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
self.engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
# ...
self.engine.load(my_qml_name)
# ...
qW = self.app.topLevelWindows()[0]
qW.setScreen(self.app.screens()[1])
```